# Two different date ranges driven by a single slicer?

Tags: powerbi, dax

My data source is a list of events. There is one column with a timestamp, and other columns are attributes (type, location, severity, etc) of that event. I would like to produce a "weekly report".

Most of the charts on this report will be based on the events that occurred in the user-selected week. Example: column chart showing count of events per location. Other charts are to show the current week's counts compared to previous weeks. Example: line chart showing the total count of events in each of the last 12 weeks

I believe I can achieve this by having two separate slicers, one for selecting the dates of the current week, the other to select the comparison range, and each chart linked to the appropriate slicer. Ideally, however, the user would be able to select a single range (e.g. the week of the report) and the second set of charts would be relative to it. Is this possible?

I produced the following example using 2 slicers, both referencing the Date field, but one slicer for each chart. I want both charts controlled by a single slicer:

[image]

Comment: An example would make it much easier to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Good call, I have added this.